# permissions problems

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, dropbox

how can i get a file or directory to be owned by two people? (have read/write permissions) i understand this involves groups, so i added user `www-data` to group `user`, then did

chown www-data:user dir

but i am not getting the effect i want.

more details:
all my web projects are rooted in drop box. i work in a windows environment, change files, and 10s later they're updated on the linux machine via dropbox. for directories/files that need write access, i do:

chown www-data:www-data dir

BUT then dropbox loses the ability to update that file, i think it's because `user` is no longer an owner of that file.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to do:

```
chown <user-account>.<shared-group> <dir>
```

And add both users to the 'shared-group' group.

(You just had the order of the group/user accounts reversed)